# Rounding to second decimal place unless the number is whole c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, output, rounding, precision

I am trying to print the average in Cpp up to 2 decimal points of the `float` num. `avg` is `float`, `sum` is `float`, `count` is `int`.

Currently if I have 10/1 for example it outputs 10.00. I want the output to be just 10. if `avg` gets value `3.1467665` for example, it should be displayed as `3.14`.

```
avg = sum/count;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << avg;
```

The rounding should be just for the output. No need to change `avg` but if it is easier, its value can be changed.

Looking for a solution using a standard before c++11.

**UPD**: the output is 27.50 when I want it to be 27.5.

Comment: The update *significantly* changes the question. It's no longer asking for *"rounding"*, but rather *"truncation"*. Granted, that still counts as rounding (either towards zero or neg. infinity), but it's not what people generally expect when they see the term *"rounding"* in isolation. Correction: It wasn't the update that changed the question. The truncation requirement was there from the beginning. The proposed answer does not address that. It would produce `3.15` when run against `3.1467665`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could choose precision according to the floating modulus of the `avg` value. The following works:

```
int main() {
  double sum = 10;
  double count = 3;
  double avg = sum/count;
  double mod;
  std::cout << std::fixed
            << std::setprecision((modf(avg, &mod) != 0.0) ? 2 : 0)
            << avg
            << std::endl;
}
```

Considering the added specifications:

- Write 2.5 instead of 2.50
- Write 3.14 for 3.1421783921, rather than 3.15

Here is a possible implementation using @IInspectable's suggested method:

```
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::fixed << avg;

  size_t pos = ss.str().find('.');
  if (pos + 2 < ss.str().size()) // If there is a '.' and more than 2 digits after it
    pos += 3;
  std::string s = ss.str().substr(0, pos); // Leave only two digits

  s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) { return ch != '0'; }).base(), s.end()); // Remove trailing zeros
  s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) { return ch != '.'; }).base(), s.end()); // Remove trailing '.' when needed
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

This will output:

- `10/4 -> 2.5`
- `10/3 -> 3.33`
- `10/2 -> 5`
- `10/7 -> 1.42`
- `3.9999 -> 3.99`

Comment: If there is a way to rewrite this using older standart(before c11), it will be great. Anyways, I will accept this as an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could replace the costly `modf` call with a simple integer conversion, e.g. `auto precision = (int(avg) != avg) ? ... : ...;`, picking an appropriate integer type given the supported range of values for `avg`.

Comment: Well the output is 27.50 when I want it to be 27.5. Is there a way this to be done too?

Comment: @KarinaK: The code isn't specific to C++11. The only change you would have to make is to spell out the type in place of `auto`. As for the new requirement, that one isn't asked for in the question. Yes, that is possible, too. At that point you should probably consider string manipulations: Construct a string representation from the value with 2 decimal places; strip trailing zeros, until there aren't any; strip a trailing `.` character. That algorithm produces the desired result.

Comment: @IInspectable, added such an implementation to my answer

Comment: That would still output `3.15` given the input `3.1467665`, not `3.14` as requested.

Comment: @IInspectable, you are right, I missed that part of the OP's question. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my problem 100%.

Comment: That algorithm doesn't reliably work either. Given the input `3.9999`, the output is now `4` instead of the desired `3.99`.

Comment: You are really trying too hard here. This, too, will fail for input with a sufficiently long sequence of `9`s trailing the decimal separator, for example (I believe the code uses the default precision, which is not necessarily the maximum needed). Instead, what you should be doing is to set the rounding mode, prior to dumping the value into a stream. This can be done using [fesetround](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) (C++11). I don't know whether the [C99 equivalent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) is guaranteed to work for C++ streams.

Comment: For a pre-C++11 implementation you might have to fall back to a C99 implementation, calling `fsetround` and `sprintf`, and put that into a `std::string` for manipulation.